# How can I close the STTP backend after completing my requests?

Tags: scala, monix, sttp

I am currently learning and playing around with STTP using the Monix backend. I am mainly stuck with closing the backend after all my requests (each request is a task) have been processed.

I have created sample/mock code to resemble my issue (to my understanding my problem is more general rather than specific to my code):

```
import sttp.client.asynchttpclient.monix._
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.reactive.Observable
import sttp.client.{Response, UriContext}

import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt

object ObservableTest extends App {

  val activities = AsyncHttpClientMonixBackend().flatMap { implicit backend =>
    val ids: Task[List[Int]] = Task { (1 to 3).toList }
    val f: String => Task[Response[Either[String, String]]] = (i: String) => fetch(uri"$i", "")
    val data: Task[List[Task[Response[Either[String, String]]]]] = ids map (_ map (_ => f("https://heloooo.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path")))
    data.guarantee(backend.close()) // If I close the backend here, I can' generate requests after (when processing the actual requests in the list)
    // I have attempted to return a Task containing a tuple of (data, backend) but closing the backend from outside of the scope did not work as I expected
  }
  import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
  val obs = Observable
    .fromTask(activities)
    .flatMap { listOfFetches =>
      Observable.fromIterable(listOfFetches)
    }
    .throttle(3 second, 1)
    .map(_.runToFuture)

  obs.subscribe()
}
```

And my fetch (api call maker) function looks like:

```
  def fetch(uri: Uri, auth: String)(implicit
      backend: SttpBackend[Task, Observable[ByteBuffer], WebSocketHandler]
  ) = {
    println(uri)
    val task = basicRequest
      .get(uri)
      .header("accept", "application/json")
      .header("Authorization", auth)
      .response(asString)
      .send()

    task
  }
```

As my main task contains other tasks, which I later need to process, I need to find an alternative way to close the Monix backend from outside. Is there a clean way to do close the backend after I consume the requests in `List[Task[Response[Either[String, String]]]]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems comes from the fact that with the sttp backend open, you are computing a list of tasks to be performed - the `List[Task[Response[Either[String, String]]]]`, but you are not running them. Hence, we need to sequence running these tasks, before the backend closes.

The key thing to do here is to create a single description of a task, that runs all of these requests while the backend is still open.

Once you compute `data` (which itself is a task - a description of a computation - which, when run, yield a list of tasks - also descriptions of computations), we need to convert this into a single, non-nested `Task`. This can be done in a variety of ways (e.g. using simple sequencing), but in your case this will be using the `Observable`:

```scala
AsyncHttpClientMonixBackend().flatMap { implicit backend =>
  val ids: Task[List[Int]] = Task { (1 to 3).toList }
  val f: String => Task[Response[Either[String, String]]] = (i: String) => fetch(uri"$i", "")
  val data: Task[List[Task[Response[Either[String, String]]]]] =
    ids map (_ map (_ => f("https://heloooo.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path")))

  val activities = Observable
    .fromTask(data)
    .flatMap { listOfFetches =>
      Observable.fromIterable(listOfFetches)
    }
    .throttle(3 second, 1)
    .mapEval(identity)
    .completedL

  activities.guarantee(
    backend.close()
  )
}
```

First note that the `Observable.fromTask(...)` is inside the outermost `flatMap`, so is created when the backend is still open. We create the observable, throttle it etc., and then comes the crucial fact: once we have the throttled stream, we evaluate each item (each item is a `Task[...]` - a description of how to send na http request) using `mapEval`. We get a stream of `Either[String, String]`, which are the results of the requests.

Finally, we convert the stream to a `Task` using `.completedL` (discarding the results), which waits until the whole stream completes.

This final task is then sequenced with closing the backend. The final sequence of side-effects that will happen, as described above, is:

1. open the backend
2. create the list of tasks (`data`)
3. create a stream, which throttles elements from the list computed by `data`
4. evaluate each item in the stream (send requests)
5. close the backend